# Rounding to the nearest Integer

Tags: python, math, rounding

I want to Round to the nearest integer if absolute difference to the nearest integer is less or equal than 0.01,

my code is with the test:

```
import unittest

def round_price(price):

  if abs(price - round(price)) <= 0.01:
    price = int(round(price))
  return price


class TestRounding(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_rounding(self):
    self.assertEqual(round_price(15.98), 15.98)
    self.assertEqual(round_price(15.99), 16)
    self.assertEqual(round_price(16.00), 16)
    self.assertEqual(round_price(16.01), 16)
    self.assertEqual(round_price(16.02), 16.02)

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Im still getting an error when testing,

self.assertEqual(round_price(16.01), 16)
AssertionError: 16.01 != 16

Comment: Check your if-clause.. maybe you want to check the absolute difference between the original price and the rounded price.

Comment: You could improve your question by saying *what* error you get when testing.  What happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What are you expecting from `if abs(round(price)) <= 0.01` if `price` is 2.993?

Comment: I updated my question with the testing and test result, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the difference between the price and the rounded price:

```
def round_price(price):

  if abs(price - round(price)) <= 0.01:
    price = int(round(price))
  return price
```

Comment: I tried it, it shows the same error, I updated my question with the testing can you please check it?

Comment: That is a feature of using floats, if for example you compared with `<= 0.010000000001`, it would probably pass.

Comment: Your updated code is still wrong... You need `abs(price - round(price))` and not `abs(round(price))` in your `if` statement.

Comment: you are right Martin it is working now

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_price(price):

    if abs(price - round(price)) <= 0.01000001:
        price = round(price)
    return price
```